playwrigh locator doesn't update the refernce for every looping time
The locator doesn't be updated for every loop
# loop scrolling last element into view until no more new elements are created`
stream_boxes = None
while True:
    stream_boxes = page.locator("//div[contains(@class,'tw-tower')]/div[@data-target]")
    stream_boxes.element_handles()[-1].scroll_into_view_if_needed()
    items_on_page = len(stream_boxes.element_handles())
    page.wait_for_timeout(2_000) # give some time for new items to load
    items_on_page_after_scroll = len(stream_boxes.element_handles())
    if items_on_page_after_scroll > items_on_page:
        continue  # more items loaded - keep scrolling
    else:


I'm not clear what you're asking. Please clearly describe the goal, provide a [mcve] of the code and the site you're automating, and ask a concrete question with actual/expected behavior. Thanks.

The loop is aiming to load more content, but the problem is the new loaded content doesn't get added to the first locator. I think the problem is about the behavior of the locator. I make a reference only for the first result, and in my opinion, it won't add the new loaded elements to the first locator.
